# Notice: Undefined index: modules in ../Converter.php line 47 - Magento 2 - (Solved)

Tags: magento2, php, module, command-line

Hi i am getting error in magento 2 frontend after creating my custom module.(Here mmm2 is my magento directory)

> a:4:{i:0;s:134:"Notice: Undefined index: modules in
>   /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Route/Config/Converter.phpon
>   line 47";i:1;s:5727:"#0
>   /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Route/Config/Converter.php(47):Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8,
>   'Undefined index...','/home/vhost/_de...', 47, Array)

If anyone face this type of error please give me solution for that. thanks in advance. comment if you needs more info.(Full detail of error as per below)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Notice: Undefined index: modules in /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Route/Config/Converter.php on line 47
    [1] => #0 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Route/Config/Converter.php(47): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home/vhost/_de...', 47, Array)
#1 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(168): Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config\Converter->convert(Object(DOMDocument))
#2 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(127): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
#3 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Route/Config/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('frontend')
#4 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Route/Config.php(82): Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config\Reader\Proxy->read('frontend')
#5 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Route/Config.php(125): Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config->_getRoutes('frontend')
#6 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/Base.php(274): Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config->getModulesByFrontName('cms')
#7 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/Base.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Array)
#8 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(50): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#11 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#12 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/app/code/Magento/Store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#15 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#18 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#21 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#24 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#26 /home/vhost/_default/mmm2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#27 {main}
    [url] => /mmm2/
    [script_name] => /mmm2/index.php
)
```

Comment: What’s your Magento version?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.1.6

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs due to permission issue of generation folder

**For Magento 2 latest versions try**

sudo chown -R current_user:www-data generated/

or

sudo chmod -R 777 generated/

**For Old Magento 2.1**

Change ownership or permission of var/generation folder in

- Change ownership

sudo chown -R current_user:www-data var/
Or

- Change permission

sudo chmod -R 777 var/

If not resolved try after removing var/   folder